# Table variable in Stored Procudure

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have developed a stored procedure in which I declared the a table variable called @TEMP_TABLE but for this line

```
SET @SQL1 = 'UPDATE PO_STAGE set PO_STAGE.ISVALID = ''N'' 
FROM ERP_ADMIN.'+@STAGE_TABLE+' PO_STAGE, @TEMP_TABLE TMP 
where PO_STAGE.ERP_PO_ID = TMP.ERP_POID'  
exec (@SQL1)
```

I am getting "Must declare the table variable "@TEMP_TABLE"." error.
Please help me in this regards.Below is the code for Stored Procedure.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [ERP_ADMIN].[VALIDATE_PURCHASE_ORDER]

    @STAGE_TABLE nvarchar(50)
    --          @errorProperty  nvarchar(50) output,
    --      @errorValue nvarchar(120) output 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @rule  INTEGER 
    DECLARE @approvalcheckingrecord   VARCHAR(200) 
    DECLARE @APP_VALIDFROMDATE DATETIME,
                @APP_VALIDTODATE DATETIME,
                @numUpdated INTEGER,
                @numInserted INTEGER,
                @systodate VARCHAR(160),
                @SQL1 [nvarchar](1200),
                @SQL2 [nvarchar](1200),
                @SOUCOL [nvarchar](200)


 --    SELECT @systodate  = CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), ERP_ADMIN.GETCURRENTDATE(), 110) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), ERP_ADMIN.GETCURRENTDATE(), 108) 

 --SELECT @systodate  = CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 110) +' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 108) 

 SET @SQL1 = ''
 SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ERP_SOURCE_COLUMN
    FROM [ERP_ADMIN].[ERP_STAGE_PROP_MAPPING] where [ERP_SOURCE_TABLE] = '''+@STAGE_TABLE+''' and [ERP_REPORT_COLOMNS] = ''Y'''

 -- PRINT @SQL1  

 SET @SQL2 = 'DECLARE rpt_cursor CURSOR GLOBAL FOR ' + @SQL1

 exec (@SQL2)  
 DECLARE        @SOURCE_COLOMN  nvarchar(80)

 SET @SOUCOL = ''
 OPEN rpt_cursor
   WHILE (0 = 0)
      --begin of while
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM rpt_cursor INTO @SOURCE_COLOMN

      IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = -1) 
       BREAK

       IF (@SOUCOL = '')
        SET @SOUCOL = 'convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL('+@SOURCE_COLOMN+',''''))+'',''+'
       ELSE  
        SET @SOUCOL = @SOUCOL + 'convert(nvarchar(255),ISNULL('+@SOURCE_COLOMN+',''''))+'',''+'

   END 

   CLOSE rpt_cursor
   DEALLOCATE rpt_cursor

   PRINT @SOUCOL
   DECLARE @TEMP_TABLE TABLE (
                ERP_POID nvarchar(50),
          ERRORCD nvarchar(50),
          ERRORMSG nvarchar(120)
   )

  SET @SQL1 = ''
  SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ERP_SOURCE_COLUMN
    FROM [ERP_ADMIN].[ERP_STAGE_PROP_MAPPING] where [ERP_SOURCE_TABLE] = '''+@STAGE_TABLE+''' and [ERP_REPORT_COLOMNS] = ''Y'''

  SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT [ERP_SOURCE_TABLE]
            ,[ERP_SOURCE_COLUMN]
            ,[ERP_MANDATORY_CHECK]
            ,[ERP_DATA_CHECK]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_PROPERTY1]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_VALUE1]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_PROPERTY2]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_VALUE2]
    FROM [ERP_ADMIN].[ERP_STAGE_PROP_MAPPING] where [ERP_SOURCE_TABLE] = '''+@STAGE_TABLE+''' and ([ERP_MANDATORY_CHECK] IN (''K'',''Y'') or [ERP_DATA_CHECK] IN (''D'',''N''))'

  PRINT @SQL1  

 SET @SQL2 = 'DECLARE stage_cursor CURSOR GLOBAL FOR ' + @SQL1


  /** DECLARE stage_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
    SELECT [ERP_SOURCE_TABLE]
            ,[ERP_SOURCE_COLUMN]
            ,[ERP_MANDATORY_CHECK]
            ,[ERP_DATA_CHECK]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_PROPERTY1]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_VALUE1]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_PROPERTY2]
            ,[ERP_ERROR_VALUE2]
    FROM [ERP_ADMIN].[ERP_STAGE_PROP_MAPPING] where [ERP_SOURCE_TABLE] = '+@STAGE_TABLE+' and ([ERP_MANDATORY_CHECK] IN ('K','Y') or [ERP_DATA_CHECK] IN ('D','N')) **/
    exec(@SQL2)      
    DECLARE  @CUR_SOURCE_TABLE [nvarchar](120),
                  @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN [nvarchar](120),
                  @CUR_MANDATORY_CHECK [nvarchar](20),
                  @CUR_DATA_CHECK [nvarchar](20),
                  @CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY1 [nvarchar](50),
                  @CUR_ERROR_VALUE1 [nvarchar](120),
                  @CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY2 [nvarchar](50),
                  @CUR_ERROR_VALUE2 [nvarchar](120)

   OPEN stage_cursor
   WHILE (0 = 0)
      --begin of while
   BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM stage_cursor INTO
             @CUR_SOURCE_TABLE,
             @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN,
             @CUR_MANDATORY_CHECK,
             @CUR_DATA_CHECK,
             @CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY1,
             @CUR_ERROR_VALUE1,
             @CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY2,
             @CUR_ERROR_VALUE2

     IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = -1) 
       BREAK

       SET @SQL1 = ''
       SET @SQL2 = ''          
      PRINT @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN
      -- IF(@CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN = 'ERP_PO_DOCNUMBER')
       IF (@CUR_MANDATORY_CHECK = 'Y' OR @CUR_MANDATORY_CHECK = 'K')
       BEGIN

        --   SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ''aaa'' as column1, ERP_PO_DOCNUMBER as column2 
        --   from PURCHASE_ORDER_STAGE where '+ @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN +' IS NULL'
       SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ERP_PO_ID, '''+@CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY1+''' as column1,'+@SOUCOL+'''|1| ERR_01 '''''+@CUR_ERROR_VALUE1+'''+'' or null in input Worksheet'' as column2
           from [ERP_ADMIN].'+@STAGE_TABLE+' where '+ @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN +' IS NULL'
       PRINT @SQL1

       INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE
        exec (@SQL1)                             
       END
       IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(@CUR_DATA_CHECK)) = 'D')
       BEGIN

        --   SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ''aaa'' as column1, ERP_PO_DOCNUMBER as column2 
        --   from PURCHASE_ORDER_STAGE where '+ @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN +' IS NULL'
       SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ERP_PO_ID, '''+@CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY2+''' as column1,'+@SOUCOL+'''|1| ERR_01 '''''+@CUR_ERROR_VALUE2+'''+'' in the input Worksheet'' as column2
           from [ERP_ADMIN].'+@STAGE_TABLE+' where isdate('+ @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN +') =0'
       PRINT @SQL1

       INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE
       exec (@SQL1)                             
       END
       IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(@CUR_DATA_CHECK)) = 'N')
       BEGIN
       PRINT @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN

       SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT ERP_PO_ID, '''+@CUR_ERROR_PROPERTY2+''' as column1,'+@SOUCOL+'''|1| ERR_01 '''''+@CUR_ERROR_VALUE2+'''+'' in the input Worksheet'' as column2
           from [ERP_ADMIN].'+@STAGE_TABLE+' where isnumeric('+ @CUR_SOURCE_COLUMN +') =0'

       PRINT @SQL1
       INSERT INTO @TEMP_TABLE
       exec (@SQL1)                             
       END

    END 

    CLOSE stage_cursor
    DEALLOCATE stage_cursor

   SET @SQL1 = '' 

   SET @SQL1 = 'UPDATE PO_STAGE set PO_STAGE.ISVALID = ''N'' FROM ERP_ADMIN.'+@STAGE_TABLE+' PO_STAGE, @TEMP_TABLE TMP where PO_STAGE.ERP_PO_ID = TMP.ERP_POID'  

   PRINT @SQL1

   exec (@SQL1)    

   /** DECLARE update_stage_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
    SELECT ERP_POID FROM @TEMP_TABLE
    DECLARE  @CURPOID [nvarchar](50)

    OPEN update_stage_cursor
     WHILE (0 = 0)
      --begin of while
    BEGIN
      FETCH NEXT FROM update_stage_cursor INTO
        @CURPOID
      IF (@@FETCH_STATUS = -1) 
      BREAK


    END  

    CLOSE update_stage_cursor
    DEALLOCATE update_stage_cursor  **/

    -- SELECT A.ERP_PO_ID FROM ERP_ADMIN.PURCHASE_ORDER_STAGE A, @TEMP_TABLE B where ERP_PO_ID = B.ERP_POID 
     SELECT ERRORCD, ERRORMSG FROM @TEMP_TABLE
 END
 GO
```

Comment: Table variable is accessible from current batch only. Use temp table instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass @TEMP_TABLE as parameter. To pass *Table* parameter you should create *table type* at first:

```
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE NAME = 'TEMP_TABLE_TYPE')    
      CREATE TYPE TEMP_TABLE_TYPE AS TABLE(
          ERP_POID nvarchar(50),
          ERRORCD nvarchar(50),
          ERRORMSG nvarchar(120)
      );
```

And use it:

```
    exec sp_executesql @Sql, N'@TEMP_TABLE TEMP_TABLE_TYPE readonly', @TEMP_TABLE
```

For epxplonation you can use this link [Passing table variable into dynamic sql](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/08/passing-table-variable-into-dynamic-sql.html).

If you find this way not obvious, I advise to use *temporary table* instead of *table varible*:

```
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP_TABLE (
          ERP_POID nvarchar(50),
          ERRORCD nvarchar(50),
          ERRORMSG nvarchar(120)
      );
```

Comment: Thanks Володин Андрей, use of temporary table in above stored procedure is working. Thanks again.